# React with Typescript: Argument of type 'never[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'StateProperties | (() => StateProperties)'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, express, react-tsx

I am practicing typescript. For the backend, I used node express typescript and for the frontend, I used react typeScript. I fetched the data from the backend and try to render it on my browser. I am getting an error: `property 'name' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339`. I think this error is coming from typescript. This is the error [visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jxsE.png)

**This is my backend setup**

```
import express = require("express");
import cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const port = 8080;
app.get("/", (req, res) =>
  res.send([
    {
      name: "John",
      age: 36
    },
    {
      name: "alex",
      age: 27
    }
  ])
);

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server running port ${port}`));
```

**This is is my React component**

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

interface StateProperties {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

//StateProperties | (() => StateProperties)
function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<StateProperties>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, []);

  const getData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/");
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    setState(data);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {state.length}

      {state.map((list, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>{list.name}</li>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to provide the interfaces/type aliases so that TypeScript will know the typings of `state`.

After creating the interface for `state`, you will need to provide the interface as the generics for `useState`.

To solve the 2nd issue, you will need to provide the `key` props to each item of the `<li>` element

```
interface StateProperties {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState<StateProperties[]>([]);

  // do the rest

return (
  <div className="App">
    {state.map(({ name, age }) => {
      return <li key={`${name}-${age}`}>{name}</li>; //FROM HERE ERROR IS COMING
    })}
  </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: Did you destructure the data?

Comment: You need to type `state` as `StateProperties[]`, as TypeScript needs to know the typings. If not, it will not know that `name` and `age` are valid properties

Comment: The other issue was more of a react related issue, whereby you have to provide each element in a list a unique `key`. For this instance, we generate the key by joining the name and age.

Comment: Also another question, when I will fetch the data from open API, do I have to use those prop types?

Comment: For TypeScript, there is no need to use React `PropTypes`. You just need interface/type aliases. If you are fetching data from API, the property that is storing the responses should be typed.